# WPF synchronize Listview with some ViewCollection

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, listview

I have a WPF `ListView` databound to an `ObeservableCollection` named `FilteredAppendixes`. Now I create a view with:

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(FilteredAppendixes);
```

The `CurrentItem` property of it will not be in sync with the Item I choose by Mouseclick in the `ListView`.  The `CurrentItem` property always remains the same first item in the `ListView`, although I clicked as mad at some of the rows.

Why is that? How can I connect the view with the `ListView` Control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you set

```
IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
```

on your listview?